# Displaying live video from a raw uncompressed byte source in C#: WPF vs. Win forms

Tags: c#, wpf, video, directshow

I have a live 16-bit gray-scale video stream that is pushed through a ring-buffer in memory as a raw, uncompressed byte stream (2 bytes per pixel, 2^18 pixels/frame, 32 frames/sec).  (This is coming from a scientific grade camera, via a PCI frame-grabber).  I would like to do some simple processing on the video (clip dynamic range, colorize, add overlays) and then show it in a window, using C#.

I have this working using Windows Forms & GDI (for each frame, build a Bitmap object, write raw 32-bit RGB pixel values based on my post-processing steps, and then draw the frame using the Graphics class).  But this uses a significant chunk of CPU that I'd like to use for other things.  So I'm interested in using WPF for its GPU-accelerated video display.  (I'd also like to start using WPF for its data binding & layout features.)

But I've never used WPF before, so I'm unsure how to approach this.  Most of what I find online about video & WPF involves reading a compressed video file from disk (e.g. WMV), or getting a stream from a consumer-grade camera using a driver layer that Windows already understands.  So it doesn't seem to apply here (but correct me if I'm wrong about this).

So, my questions:

- Is there a straighforward, WPF-based way to play video from raw, uncompressed bytes in memory (even if just as 8-bit grayscale, or 24-bit RGB)?
- Will I need to build DirectShow filters (or other DirectShow/Media Foundation-ish things) to get the post-processing working on the GPU?

Also, any general advice / suggestions for documentation, examples, blogs, etc that are appropriate to these tasks would be appreciated.  Thanks!

---

**Follow-up:** After some experimentation, I found `WriteableBitmap` to be fast enough for my needs, and extremely easy to use correctly: Simply call `WritePixels()` and any `Image` controls bound to it will update themselves.  `InteropBitmap` with memory-mapped sections is noticeably faster, but I had to write p/invokes to kernel32.dll to use it on .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My VideoRendererElement, though very efficient, does use some hackery to make it work.  You may also want to experiment with the WriteableBitmap in .NET 3.5 SP1.

Also the InteropBitmap is very fast too.  Much more efficient than the WB as it's not double buffered.  Though it can be subject to video tearing.

Comment: You should have properly linked the off site resource

Answer (score 1):

Some further Google-searching yielded this:

http://www.codeplex.com/VideoRendererElement

which I'm looking into now, but may be the right approach here.  Of course further thoughts/suggestions are still very much welcome.