# D3DImage: display bitmap from byte array

Tags: c#, wpf, d3dimage

I have raw bitmap data (pixel colors, 32 bit) in an array.
Is there a simple way to display such a "sprite" on a D3DImage?
Preferably without use of thirdparty libs (such as SharpDX).

Background:
I have raw bitmap frames coming from unmanaged DLL and I need to display them with high framerate/low CPU usage in WPF. So far I've tried WriteableBitmap and InteropBitmap, but they are too slow (I get ~110 fps on maximized window (1680x1050 display), Core i5; and this is just a simple test with filling the memory. I believe that modern computers should do this much faster without using 100% CPU core time).
I'm also looking at VideoRendererElement ([Displaying live video from a raw uncompressed byte source in C#: WPF vs. Win forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529300/displaying-live-video-from-a-raw-uncompressed-byte-source-in-c-wpf-vs-win-for)), but this is a bit overcomplicated (involves unmanaged dlls, regsvr32 registration, etc).

As I see from D3DImage samples, it achieves good framerates without stressing the CPU. I wonder if it is possible to use it for bitmap display.

**UPD:** 
I've found this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113991/Using-Direct2D-with-WPF

Which is basically what I was looking for. I've plugged it into my project, and it is on par with InteropBitmap, even a little bit slower. Looks like memory performance is a bottleneck in my case. In both cases most time is spent on copying bitmap (I use unmanaged memcpy).

Comment: Interesting, on other computer, which has similar core i5 CPU, but dedicated GPU (insted of CPU integrated), I get 270 fps on a full-hd screen (1920х1080 window size)

Comment: could you share an example of how you solved this problem?  I am trying to display a byte array (image from a camera) in a D3DImage.  My only difference is that before I display the byte array, I am manipulating the array on the GPU.  My desire is to display from the GPU (using InterOp??) without unloading it from the GPU.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, no, I ended up using InteropBitmap.

Comment: Gotcha...Thanks anyway.